# Double Click addOnItemTouchListener of a Recycler View item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In recycler view i have more than one item click listener and i used same adapter for more than one fragment

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new MyRecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new MyRecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View views, final int position) {
                    //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
                    view = views;
                    share_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.share_txt);
                    complaint_id_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.complaint_id_txt);
                    comment_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_txt);
                    like_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_count);
                    like_id_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_id_txt);
                    like_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lik_img);
                    complaint_imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.complaint_img);

                    complaint_id = complaint_id_txt.getText().toString();
                    final String like_str = like_id_txt.getText().toString();


                    comment_txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Comment.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    complaint_imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            complaintAssign(position);

                            complaint_id = complaintList.get(position).getComplaintId();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_ComplaintDetail.class);
                            intent.putExtra("position", position);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    like_txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (like_str.equalsIgnoreCase("Liked")) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "You have already liked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (like_str.equalsIgnoreCase("Like")) {
                                like_txt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navy));
                                like_img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.like));
                                lik = likeJson();
                                if (lik == 2323) {
                                    like_txt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
                                    like_img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unlike));
                                } else {

                                }


                            }

                        }
                    });
                    like_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (like_str.equalsIgnoreCase("Liked")) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "You have already liked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (like_str.equalsIgnoreCase("Like")) {
                                like_txt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navy));
                                like_img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.like));
                                lik = likeJson();
                                if (lik == 2323) {
                                    like_txt.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
                                    like_img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unlike));
                                } else {

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select Category",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
    );
```

its working fine but it works only on 2nd click on 1st click it wont do any operation. recyclerView.setFocusable(false); and recyclerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); But it wont work for me can anyone help for me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not click listener on your adapter class or ViewHolder? by this code you have to click twice. just simply add click listener on Image in the holder class

Comment: i used that adapter class for more than one fragment and i have to get some values based on position

Answer (score 1):

You are setting complaint_img's listener only after a click on recyclerView element, so you have to click twice for it to make any action. Move complaint_img.setOnClickListener() to adapter of your recyclerView.

Comment: I had used my adapter for more than one fragment

Comment: Then do not set complait_img's on click but rather fire it in onItem's listener

Comment: I cant understand can you give some example?

Comment: azizbekian's answer is perfect example of what I mean

Comment: Thank you, But i have to do more than one item click in it

Comment: After your edition of the question it's looks like you have to set these listeners in your adapter